# What is the right Term for this regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a validation for text fields in Python.
Now I want to implement the following regex for validation.

However, I have problems escaping the expression.
can someone help me here?

```
def regex_1_4_9_digits(data, min=1, max=9):
    pattern = f'[A-Z0-9]{{{min},{max}}}'
    pattern1 = f'^\\s*-?[A-Z0-9]{{{min,max}}}\\s*$'
    output = re.match(pattern, data)
    return output
```

I want to use `pattern1` but there is a mistake with the escape of the ""and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: In `pattern1` you did not properly put `min` and `max` in braces (separately), like you did in `pattern`. Around the separating comma there are two braces missing. Seems a typo-kind of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside interpolated string literals, a literal `{` is defined as `{{` and a literal `}` is set using `}}`.

You should use

```
pattern1 = f'^\\s*-?[A-Z0-9]{{{n},{m}}}\\s*$'
                              ^^^ ^^^
```

Or,

```
pattern1 = rf'^\s*-?[A-Z0-9]{{{n},{m}}}\s*$'
```

I suggest using `n` for the minimum threshold and `m` for maximum.

The `{{{n},{m}}}` should be read as

- `{{` - `{` string
- `{n}` - the value of the `n` variable
- `,` - a comma (string)
- `{m}` - the value of the `m` variable
- `}}` - a `}` string.